# Where to find a complete list of document action functions in JS

Tags: document-library, javascript, core-js

I'm tasked with taking an inventory of all document action functions in **core.js**

Is there a list somewhere online that provides a list of all user options from a document list menu? [If I can get it broken down by 2007 vs. 2010 that'd be a huge bonus].

I'm trying to avoid having to inventory and manually read through all functions in the file so I can focus on those specific to documents.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just curious... why are doing this? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @KitMenke my work assignment involves research on event tracking in SharePoint, and I'm currently focused on user actions involving documents.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunatley this one does not answer your question. The `core.js` file is not intended for your use directly (even though it might work) - it will/can change from version to version or build to build.

You should take a look at the methods defined in `SP.js`, `SP.Core.js`, `CUI.js` etc. The supported objects and functions are documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee538253

Comment: I'm not interested in using the functions directly - my research/work is not involved with coding interfaces for new user events. I'm just interested in trying to identify what the set is in core.js

Comment: If you're doing research, then just start researching core.js :-)

Comment: which is what I'm doing. I'm just trying to see if, as I graze my eyes over this sandpaper, there is faster, less painful way to do this. i.e. documentation.